# Azure DevOps pipeline stage - stop execution until specific users approve

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have a stage which runs this job (not exactly the same but same concept). The issue with this is it will notify those users but anyone who has the right permissions is able to approve this stage (which I want to limit it only to specific users). Is there another task that can achieve this?

```
jobs:  
  - job: waitForValidation
    dependsOn: 'previousJobName'
    displayName: Wait for external validation  
    pool: server    
    timeoutInMinutes: 4320 # job times out in 3 days
    steps:   
    - task: ManualValidation@0
      timeoutInMinutes: 1440 # task times out in 1 day
      inputs:
        notifyUsers: |
          test@test.com
          example@example.com
        instructions: 'Please validate the build configuration and resume'
        onTimeout: 'reject'
```

Something similar to Release Pipelines 'Pre-deployment approvals'

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During my test, I suppose that you could add the manual approval by add the [environment deployment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/environments?view=azure-devops).
[image]

You could add the environment sample like code below.

```
  jobs:
  - deployment: Deploy
    displayName: Deploy
    environment: $(environmentName)
    pool:
      vmImage: 
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
          - task: xxx
```

And in your target environment, add the approval checks with screenshot below.
[image]
[image]

Comment: I will have to confirm in a few days but will it limit it to the approvers only in that list?

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct method, unfortunately, but there are two different tricks to achieve the outcome you want, i.e., limit approval to only specific users. I prefer #2 as it's easy to implement and manage/maintain across multiple pipelines. If you have just a few pipelines, #1 will work too if you can/have-access to change security settings of the Azure Pipelines.

**Manual Validation**

[Manual Validation in Azure DevOps Pipelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/manual-validation-v0?view=azure-pipelines) does not support limiting the users who approve the confirmation step by default. However, you can fix pipeline permissions, limiting the number of people who can do validations.

1. Go to a pipeline under **Pipelines -> Pipelines**.
2. Click the three-dot menu and select **Manage security**.
3. Click on any item under Groups or Users and disable **Queue builds** permission. Set this option to **Deny** to disable a user's or group's access: they can not validate deployments then.

[image]

**Environments + Approvals**

Azure Pipelines aka YAML-based Pipelines support Environments, which in turn supports Approvals: an official feature from Azure DevOps to do exactly what you want: allow just a bunch of people to approve deployments. And fortunately, you can create an environment with zero/no resources in it, i.e., it can be simply a dummy environment you use for managing approvers who can approve your pipeline's deployments. When ready, follow these steps:

1. Go to Environments under **Pipelines -> Environments**.
2. Click **New environment** -> type any **Name** and **Description** and select **None** for/under **Resource** and then click **Create**.
3. Click **Approvals and checks** and click the **+** (plus) button -> **Approvals** -> **Next**, then add users under **Approvers** and click **Create**.

[image]

Also, add the environment to your pipeline's YAML script as following:

```yaml
jobs:  
  - job: waitForValidation
    dependsOn: 'previousJobName'
    displayName: Wait for external validation
    environment: "Environment_Name_HERE" # REPLACE THIS
    pool: server    
    timeoutInMinutes: 4320 # job times out in 3 days
    steps:
      # ADD YOUR STEPS HERE
```